# Check function if event has an accepted offer?

Tags: php

I need to check if an event has an offer and i have made this function

```
public function hasAcceptedOffer()
{
    foreach ($this->offers as $offer) {

        if( $offer->accepted == 1 ){
        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}
```

But i think this can be made better, more optimized. Because if there are a lot of offers i don't want to go through all of them. What i want is that if a function finds an offer that is accepted it should stop further iteration.

Comment: I think you did good. The function will return if it found an accepted offer. NOTE that you have a error with your "if" statement. you missed a {

Comment: Is there a break; option in php? how can i break the iteration?

Comment: You can sort `$this->offers` by accepted, then you can check only first element

Comment: you have break option in "switch - case" statements. but you don't need it. this function is fine

Comment: @Anant i need that else part because i am using this function in another if statement and if it doesn't return false it will return nothing

Comment: Don't sort offers! sorting will most likely to iterate over all of them!

Comment: How do you mean don't sort offers? i have saved them in my DB and i'm just iterating through them.

Comment: I see.. I meant don't sort them in your script. But you can fetch them from the DB sorted. That will be much, much more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you did good here.

You can remove the else part by doing this

```
public function hasAcceptedOffer()
{
    foreach ($this->offers as $offer) {

        if( $offer->accepted == 1 ){
           return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: @lewis4u that is completely bad logic. I up-voted your question because you shown us some code effort and ask your question in proper manner. Not for marking purpose.Thanks

Comment: @lewis4u you can go with any one. I have no issue

Comment: @Anant someone downvoted your answer and it wasn't me :(

Comment: @lewis4u look.. you should do what you think that will help other people. Nobody's life depend on your upvote. Do what you think is right. Good luck!

Comment: i have just accepted carmels answer, and someone has downvoted Anants answer and it wasn't me

Comment: @lewis4u  leave it. No issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only care if *any* offer was accepted, and you don't need to know which one, I like to do it like this:

```
public function hasAcceptedOffer()
{
    foreach($this->offers as $offer) {
        if($offer->accepted !== 1)
            continue;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Each iteration of the loop will quickly skip to the next one if it doesn't match your desired criteria, it will return immediately when it finds the first positive result and skip processing the others (since you don't care anyway) and return false if no matches are found.

If you want to collect the offers that were accepted, you can amend it like so:

```
public function getAcceptedOffers()
{
    $results = array();

    foreach($this->offers as $offer) {
        if($offer->accepted !== 1)
            continue;

        $results[] = $offer;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: @carmel's answer is slightly more efficient and fits the OP's stated use case more exactly, but I thought it relevant to also share a method I've found to be effective when the use-case gets a bit more complex.